# Interesting property of $\sin{kx}/x$

Tags: limits

I worked out this afternoon with a student that $$ \lim_{x\to 0} \left( \dfrac{\sin(kx)}{x} \right) = k.$$

([*Graph to fiddle around with if you like -- press the play button for some very satisfying graph animation*](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/soouh2sgrn))

Evaluated the limit using L'hopital's rule since $\sin(5x)$ and $x$ both approach 0:

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} \left( \dfrac{\sin(kx)}{x} \right) = \lim_{x\to 0} \left( \dfrac{k\cos(kx)}{1} \right) = k $$

I don't understand how the limit as $x$ approaches zero depends on $k$ at all. The only think I could think of is Taylor expanding: $$ \dfrac{\sin(kx)}{x} = \frac{1}{x}\left(kx-\frac{k^3x^3}{3!}+\frac{k^5x^5}{5!}+\dots \right) = \left(k-\frac{k^3x^2}{3!}+\frac{k^5x^4}{5!}+\dots \right) $$ so even just plugging in $0$, you get $k$. And this makes sense to me.

But I'm perplexed as to how altering $k$ affects the graph of the function. Normally swapping $x$ for $kx$ "stretches or shrinks" the graph of a function horizontally, but not vertically. For the trig functions, increasing $k$ "compresses" the graph horizontally, but doesn't do anything to the value of the function at $0$. In this function, as k increases, the graph does get compressed, but it also gets stretched vertically. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get just a horizontal compression, $x$ must be replaced by $kx$ in all places where there is an $x$. i.e.

$$\frac{\sin{x}}{x}\to\frac{\sin{kx}}{kx}$$

However, in your case, it is just

$$\frac{\sin{x}}{x}\to\frac{\sin{kx}}{x}$$

Notice that you are missing the factor of $1/k$ in your transform relative to the other. This means that your new function is not just compressed horizontally  by a factor of $k$, it is also stretched vertically by a factor of $k$. And thus, your graph is perhaps taller than you expected.

Comment: :D thank you! This makes total sense

Answer (score 1):

But $kx$ is
the argument of the
$\sin$ function.
It makes the argument
$k$ times as large
as $x$.

Since
$\sin(z)
\approx z$
for small $z$,
$\sin(kx)
\approx kx
$
for small $x$.

Answer (score 0):

Look at it the other way round $ f(y)=\dfrac{\sin(y)}{y}$ then: $$ \lim_{y\to 0} = 1.$$ Now do the substitution $y=kx$, as you said stretching the graph nothing happens to the limit: $$ \lim_{x\to 0} f(kx) = 1.$$ but $$ \lim_{x\to 0} \left( \dfrac{\sin(kx)}{kx} \right) = 1 \equiv \lim_{x\to 0} \left( \dfrac{\sin(kx)}{x} \right) = k.$$